# Using Node Buffer or fileStream with formData file upload

Tags: angularjs, node.js, fs

**Update**: I have more or less solved the problem using multipart (`app.use(multipart({uploadDir: __dirname + '/../uploads'}))`from [these instructions](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload/wiki/node.js-example)), but still don't know why my original code (below) fails.

There have been numerous variations on this question, and I have tried the ideas there without success. I'm using a [file uploading directive](https://github.com/leon/angular-upload) (and have since tried another open source alternative) to send a binary file to a node server, that runs the following code (based on an SO answer I can't now refind):

```
exports.receive = function(req, res) {

    var fitFileBuffer = new Buffer('');
    // req.setEncoding("binary");    //doesn't help

    req.on('data', function(chunk) { 
        fitFileBuffer = Buffer.concat([fitFileBuffer, chunk]);
    });

    req.on('end', function() { 
        fs.writeFileSync(
            "today2.fit",
            fitFileBuffer,
            'binary');
        res.send(200);
    });
};
```

If I upload `today.fit` and compare to `today2.fit`, they have the same Kb of data, but are not identical, and subsequent code fails to process the file. Given that this happens with two pieces of third party code I suspect the problem lies with my code.

Here are the details from the client side of the POST being made
[image: Network settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: the client post details helped. You're not posting a file stream (which would have worked) you're posting a form stream. The good news is there are good modules for handling form streams.

You'll need to pipe the request stream into a form handling stream (such as busboy) which will handle the `------WebKitFormBoundary. . .` part and them give you the file(s) as stream(s)

https://github.com/mscdex/busboy

```
var Busboy = require('busboy');

exports.receive = function(req, res, next) {
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      var fileWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream('today2.fit');
      file.pipe(fileWriteStream);
    });
    busbody.on('finish', function() {
      res.send(201);
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
};
```

Comment: I needed to change this to `req.pipe(fileWriteStream)` to avoid runtime error, but I ended up with what looks to be the same `today2.fit` as with my original code. When I used the node debugger I found that `'end'` didn't seem to be called, although that did work with my original code. Any more ideas?

Comment: Thanks, I had it as `ws` and missed that one when I refactored.  re: 'end' not firing, ahh that one, I always forget that one. Writtable streams don't emit 'end' they emit 'finish' I updated the code.

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't do it for me. See the update in the question as I have found a solution, but based on adding unipart express middleware. I'm still confused

Comment: note I skipped error handling, you should add error handlers to both `busboy` and `fileWriteStream` or else errors will crash your whole server.

Comment: Thanks so much.  So I've now learnt there is a distinction between multipart and fileStreams. I'm left thinking that, if I'm using a multipart client uploader, then the BEST way forward is with Multer on the backend rather than trying to squeeze into Streams?

Comment: It's hard to convince the browser to upload a plain old file stream, the good news is a multipart stream with a single file has ~0 overhead so it isn't a big deal. So I'd say your current `app.use(multipart` is good enough unless you want to work some stream magic (`app.use(multipart` uses streams under the hood)

Answer (score 3):

In the end, when I realised that I wanted to avoid saving to disk, I modified generalhenry's code with some stuff from busyboy's site and my own use of a Buffer:

```
exports.receive = function (req, res, next) {
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    var fileBuffer = new Buffer('');

    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        file.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
            fileBuffer = Buffer.concat([fileBuffer, data]);
        });

        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
            genXmlFromString(fileBuffer.toString(), function(data) {
                res.json(data);
            });
        });

    });

    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        console.log("'finish'");
    });

    req.pipe(busboy);
};
```